# Hibernate query left outer join.

Tags: hibernate, hql

```
SELECT Table1.name,Table1.url,Table1.address,Table1.city,Table1.state,Table1.ErrorMsg as Msg,
sum(Table2.id IS NOT NULL) as QE,Table4.tp as PT FROM Table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.Table1Id=Table1.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 ON Table3 .id=Table1.pdId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table4 ON Table4.venueId=Table3 .id
WHERE Table1.visible = 1 GROUP BY Table1.id ORDER BY Table1.name,Table1.city,Table1.state,QE,PT;
```

I am new to hql have converted everything based on objects but am clueless based on how do i frame the left outer join in hql. Tried using as **`Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException:`** The sum aggregate function throws:
**Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting CLOSE, found 'IS' near line 1,** Please help

Comment: Is the above supposed to be an HQL query? It's not. If the above is a SQL query you tried to translate to HQL, then why don't you show us the HQL query that you tried?

Comment: The above is the hql query i am trying to form Table1,TABLE2,TABLE3,TABLE4 are the object i've created

Comment: Then read the documentation on associations and joins in HQL. There is no ON clause in HQL. It's unnecessary because you create joins using associations between entities. And you must assign aliases to your entities. And, as in SQL, every column in the select clause must be in the group by clause. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql